# React - how to render multiple buttons with a regular for loop?

Tags: reactjs

Sorry if its very basic but:
when rendering multiple buttons (0-9) in an iteration - What is the difference btw map and for loop ? Why does the for loop only renders the first element (0) while map works fine? Why do I have to first push the buttons into an array and return that then (as seen on other examples) ? Can I use regular for loop and render buttons without pushing it into an arary?
Thanks!

```
 import React from 'react';

    const Keys = () => {        
       const renderKeys = () => {
         //works fine
          var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
          return arr.map((val) => {
              return <button>{val}</button>
            })                 
        };

        const renderKeys = () => {       
              //does not work    
              for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
               return <button>{i}</button>
            }
        };

        return (
            <div>
                {renderKeys()}
            </div>
        )
    };
```

Comment: Hi @javascripting, just provided you a solution below. Let me know if you need any further explanation regarding this topic :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you call `return` inside a for-loop it stops executing the loop. That's why you only get back the first button.

However, calling `return` inside a `.map()` will not stop the loop from iterating. Instead you use `return` to explicitly define what you want to have in a new array.

Note that `.map()` creates a brand new array by using elements from an existing array. You are free to utilize those elements any way you want which makes it suitable for rendering JSX.

Example:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const numbersMultipledByTwo = numbers.map((number) => {
   return <div>{ number * 2 }</div>
})
```

Theoretically, you could accomplish the same effect using a for-loop but that will also require help from a second array.

### Working code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component{
  getButtonsUsingMap = () => {
    const array = [1, 2, 3 ,4, 5]

    return array.map((number) => {
      return <button>{number}</button>
    })

  }

  getButtonsUsingForLoop = (num) => {
    const array = []

    for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++){
      array.push(<button>{i}</button>)
    }

    return array
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h4>Using .map()</h4>
        {this.getButtonsUsingMap()}
        <h4>using for-loop</h4>
        {this.getButtonsUsingForLoop(5)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

In that `getButtonsUsingForLoop`  function, you can see there are more explicit demands to make it work. First we need to satisfy the argument. Then initialize a new array. Then define a boundary for the loop. Iterate and push JSX to the empty-array. Then finally return that array. So the logic is not very succinct.

Whereas on the other-hand, a `.map()` essentially handles all of that. As long as you have a pre-existing array to iterate over (which 99% of the time you will be dealing with some sort of state or props-array.)

See sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-leftpad-lt5ml

Answer (score 5):

> What is the difference btw map and for loop?

`.map()` iterates an array (and arrays only) while a for loop could be lazily summarized as a more "general" loop mechanism that is independent of any specific data type.

> Why does the for loop only renders the first element (0) while map works fine?

Because you're returning from the function in the first iteration of the for loop with

```js
const renderKeys = () => {       
  //does not work    
  for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    return <button>{i}</button> // this returns from the function you're in
  }
};
```

`.map()` works fine because it returns a new array from iterating the input-array, e.g.:

```js
const renderKeys = () => {
  // works fine
  var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  return arr.map((val) => { // here you return the new array created by map
    return <button>{val}</button>
  });
};
```

> Why do I have to first push the buttons into an array and return that then (as seen on other examples)?

basically to "imitate" what map does, e.g. creating a new array from the iteration.

> Can I use regular for loop and render buttons without pushing it into an array?

Directly return you mean? I don't think it's possible, but maybe somebody else does know a way!

Why I think it's not possible?

```js
return (
  <div>
    {renderKeys()}
  </div>
)
```

in JSX you return a function and you can't pass a for loop as a function argument directly, e.g. this:

```js
return (
  <div>
  for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    <button>{i}</button>
  }
  </div>
)
```

would most likely give you a syntax error...